# How to reliably obtain a folder's view state property bag

Tags: c++, winapi, properties, com

I'm trying to implement a feature that allows the user to save a given Explorer folder view layout, and then apply that same view to other folders as desired.

After digging around and experimenting, it seems like the way to obtain and save a folder view would be to call `SHGetViewStatePropertyBag`.  But as far as I can tell, that function requires you to know a folder-type GUID.  The call has to look something like this:

```
SHGetViewStatePropertyBag(  pidlFolder,
                            L"Shell\\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}",
                            SHGVSPB_FOLDERNODEFAULTS,
                            IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropBag) );
```

As a practical matter, that GUID is probably `FOLDERTYPEID_Generic`, `FOLDERTYPEID_Documents`, `FOLDERTYPEID_Videos`, `FOLDERTYPEID_Pictures`, or `FOLDERTYPEID_Music`, but that doesn't seem to be a given.

Furthermore, I'm not sure all folders have a folder type specified under the "Shell" key.

So is there a reliable or better way of obtaining a folder's view state property bag?

Comment: I think you can just use "Shell" as the bag name without the specific GUID.

Comment: A given shell folder/view can answer the undocumented IFolderType interface (google on it). Then, for standard views, the type is itself stored in a "FolderType" value in the state property bag you open using simply "Shell". Otherwise, I think it'll be FOLDERTYPEID_Generic

Comment: @SimonMourier Can you briefly explain how to use an undocumented interface?  Thank you very much.

Comment: You just have to find the definition somewhere (for example from here: https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/shell32/interfaces/ifoldertype.htm) and then declare it manually in some .h, for example like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/QFnzQK1u and then you can use it like any other interface. This one is pretty self-explanatory. If you have an IShellView, you can QueryInterface on it. If you don't have the IID, you can try here on this online tool (I wrote): https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=IID_IFolderType

Comment: Awesome, it worked.  Thank you very much!